# Swift Заменить кнопку "назад"

Tags: swift

Пытался так скрыть кнопку "назад" и вставить на ее место другую

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesBackButton = true

self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

let backButton1 = UIBarButtonItem (title: "Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GoToBack))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton1
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(GoToBack))

self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([backButton1], animated: true)
```

но кнопка "назад" не думает уходить, как стояла, так и стоит, не подскажите, как это пофиксить ?

на других `vc` работает и скрывает кнопку, не могу понять, что с этим не так, вызываю текущий (проблемный) `vc` таак :

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй такой вариант.

```
guard let secondVC: SecondVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC else {return}
 let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
 backItem.title = ""
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```